# Google Cloud Endpoints using Google Cloud Run Error: could not handle the request

Tags: google-cloud-run, google-cloud-endpoints-v2

I have setup Google Cloud endpoints (open-api.yaml) that points to Google Functions. I have created the API Gateway server using Google Cloud Run. I tested the same and found it working.

After doing some update in the YAML and Google Functions I now get an **Error: could not handle the request**. It is a server 500 error. The YAML file is as follows:

```
swagger: '2.0'
info:
  title: API gateway
  description: Gateway on Cloud Endpoints with a Google Cloud Functions backend
  version: 1.0.0
host: xxxx-service-abcd-uc.a.run.app
schemes:
  - https
produces:
  - application/json
paths:
  /auth/signup:
    post:
      summary: Create a new user
      operationId: authSignup
      x-google-backend:
        address: https://us-central1-project-id.cloudfunctions.net/api-auth-function
        path_translation: APPEND_PATH_TO_ADDRESS
      responses:
        '200':
          description: A successful response
          schema:
            type: string
  /auth/login:
    post:
      summary: Logs in an existing user
      operationId: authLogin
      x-google-backend:
        address: https://us-central1-project-id.cloudfunctions.net/api-auth-function
        path_translation: APPEND_PATH_TO_ADDRESS
      responses:
        '200':
          description: A successful response
          schema:
            type: string
  /auth/check:
    get:
      summary: check
      operationId: authCheck
      x-google-backend:
        address: https://us-central1-project-id.cloudfunctions.net/api-auth-function
        path_translation: APPEND_PATH_TO_ADDRESS
      responses:
        '200':
          description: A successful response
          schema:
            type: string
```

When I call the url: `https://xxx--service-abcd-uc.a.run.app/auth/login` with a post call from Postman or `https://xxxx-service-abcd-uc.a.run.app/auth/check` with a get call from Postman or the browser I get this error.

The logs on Google Cloud Run merely have entries like:

`GET 500 700 B 184 msChrome 79 https://xxxx-service-abcd-uc.a.run.app/auth/check` 
or

`POST 500 622 B 99 PostmanRuntime/7.22.0 https://xxxx-service-abcd-uc.a.run.app/auth/login`

Since it was earlier working, there must be some silly error that I am not able to detect. Thanks for any help.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you have provided a Docker container that is executed by Cloud Run.  If you target it directly, does it work?

Comment: Thanks @Kolban for the response. Yes, I used the container that Google documentation suggested to run the end point. When I call the Google Run url, it gives me the same error. Note that in the logs I have used the Postman and Chrome browser method to call a Post and Get route directly. The google function I checked works

Comment: I confess I had it working yesterday ... just made some changes. Hence I suspect that something I goofed in the yaml

Comment: This is the steps that I followed: https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/get-started-cloud-functions

Answer (score 3):

I deleted the Google Run service and recreated it with simple API paths and it seems to work.

Comment: When you say you recreated it with simple API paths does this mean you had to change the `openapi-functions.yaml` in any way?

Comment: Yes. As mentioned I had it working. Then when I enhanced the yaml (added more paths) and the logic within the google functions to satisfy them, it bombed. Just wanted to put here on record that perhaps the error was my bad.